# DatePicker needing 2 clicks to update error, Formik and Yup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I have this Material UI DatePicker:

```
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                            <DatePicker 
                                label="Date of birth" 
                                format="DD/MM/YYYY" 
                                value = {values.dob}

                                sx={{ width: '50%' }}
                                slotProps={{
                                    textField: {
                                    id: 'dob',
                                    helperText: touched.dob ? errors.dob : "",
                                    error: touched.dob && Boolean(errors.dob),
                                    },
                                    }}
                                    onChange={(value) => { 
                                        setFieldValue('dob', value ? dayjs(value).toDate() : null);
                                        setFieldTouched('dob', true); 
                                    }}
                                />
                        </LocalizationProvider>
                    </Grid>
```

The problem I have is that my `DatePicker` only works at the second time.

It says `required` at the first time instead of saying `Date of birth cannot be in the future` then at the second time it says `Date of birth cannot be in the future`.

I always need 2 clicks to change it, if it says `Date of birth cannot be in the future` and then I change it to yesterday it will still say "Date of birth cannot be in the future", I need to click something else per example the `textfield name` and click somewhere else and it will update.

If someone can help me it would be great.

Formik:

```
    const { values, errors, touched, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched } = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: "",
            dob: null,
            email: "",
        },   
        validationSchema: formSchema,
        
    });
```

Yup:

```
export const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().matches(nameRules, 'Please enter a valid name').max(40).required("Required"),
    dob: yup.date().max(new Date(), 'Date of birth cannot be in the future').required('Required'), 
    email: yup.string().email("Please enter a valid email").required("Required"),
});
```

I found out that what is making it having to be clicked 2 times to change is the `setFieldTouched('dob', true);` but if I remove it then I will lose my helperText.

I am expecting for it to change with one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out why, the `setFieldTouched` needs to come first.

```
onChange={(value) => { 
  setFieldTouched('dob', true);
  setFieldValue('dob', value ? dayjs(value).toDate() : null);
}}
```

instead of:

```
onChange={(value) => { 
  setFieldValue('dob', value ? dayjs(value).toDate() : null);
  setFieldTouched('dob', true);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to the order in which Formik's `setFieldValue` and `setFieldTouched` are being called in your DatePicker's `onChange` handler. The `setFieldTouched` is being called after `setFieldValue`, and Formik might not be updating the touched state in time for the first render.
To resolve this issue, you can try updating the order of these calls. Move the `setFieldTouched` before `setFieldValue`

If the issue persists, you can also try using `validateOnChange` and `validateOnBlur` options in the `useFormik` configuration to control when Formik runs validation.

For example:

```js
const {
  values,
  errors,
  touched,
  handleBlur,
  handleChange,
  handleSubmit,
  setFieldValue,
  setFieldTouched
} = useFormik({
  initialValues: { name: "", dob: null, email: "" },
  validationSchema: formSchema,
  validateOnChange: true, // Set this option to true
  validateOnBlur: true // Set this option to true
});
```

Comment: That was it, I found it out 10 seconds after publishing the question , I only had to change the order, thank you anyway!